# Use entry in Microsoft Access form to retrieve file based on entry

Tags: database, ms-access, photo

I am an intern for an environmental non-profit. We have entered data into an access form. A sample entry is "Photo ID: 0075" which actually refers to a file called P1000075.jpg in one of our folders. I was wondering if there was a way to link this number entry with the actual file, and how I might begin going about to accomplish this. Any nods in the appropriate direction or help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's generally 3 approaches to file management 1) store file in database 2) store file in external path/site but have pathing to the file contained within the application along with a file pointer (what you have I think) 3) store file on a server and include a hyperlink URL or UNC path to the document.  You could have a textand store the complete UNC path to the file... but what benefit would it have actually linking the document?  Is there a reason it wasn't linked to begin with?  Understand why things are the way they are before you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FileDialog to choose a file and store that choice in a table

http://599cd.com/tips/access/150405_filedialog/